# Why does jQuery's animate break when I put blocking functions in the queue?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, queue

When I use `console.log(elem.queue());` the first time it returns an empty array `[]` but if I make it more specific aka `console.log(elem.queue()[0]);` it gives me individual functions in the correct order. After the first time, when I use `console.log(elem.queue());` it returns the correct length but it returns the functions in a different order than what they should be and sometimes it returns undefined. But still when I use `console.log(elem.queue()[0]);` it returns what is expected. Here is my code and what gets outputted:

```
//The correct queue order is: animate, run, animate

console.log(elem.queue('jChain'));    //1: []
                                      //2+: [run(){}, animate(){}, undefined x 1]

console.log(elem.queue('jChain')[0]); //animate(){} 
console.log(elem.queue('jChain')[1]); //run(){}
console.log(elem.queue('jChain')[2]); //animate(){}
```

As you can see, when I specifically select from the queue, it is correct. But when I select the whole queue, everything messes up. **Can someone please tell me what is going on and why?**

---

**UPDATE**
*Code that creates the queue:*

```
console.log(queue); /* [{args:Array[2], method:"animate"},
                     *  {args:Array[2], method:"run"}, 
                     *  {args:Array[2], method:"animate"}] */
elem.clearQueue('jChain');
$.each(queue, function(key, value){
  if(value.method == 'animate'){
    value.args[1] = {duration:value.args[1], queue:'jChain' /*,complete:function(){elem.dequeue('jChain');}*/ };
    elem[value.method].apply(elem, value.args);
  }else{
    run.apply(elem, value.args);
  }
});

function run(fn, args){
  args = args || [];
  self = this;
  self.queue('jChain', function(next){
    if(fn)
        fn.apply(self, args);
    next();
  });
}
```

So why it does this weird displaying, I have no idea. I am trying to debug this code still and I figure that this is probably what's holding me back. I don't want the 2nd animate to execute until my run function has completed, and it seems like it should work but really it fails. 

[**Here is a jsFiddle of my code.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ww8QX/3/) - Make sure you have the console open when testing. If the console is not open, it will look like it works so have it open. Notice how "Subtitle" flicks back on instead of fading in, and also notice the difference in the queue orders.

Comment: Can you post the code that is creating this Queue?

Comment: The animation in the fiddle works fine if you set the `for` loop to 10...

Comment: @Owlvark - Which suggests that my run and my 2nd animate calls are being executed simultaneously. And I have no idea why that is haha.

Comment: Not really. If you put an `alert()` in `speak`, the 2nd animate only fires after you click ok.

Comment: @Owlvark - Hence my confusion. ;)

Comment: you could rename this question to "Why do jQuery's animate break with blocking functions in the queue"; the queue array is as it should. i'll add a bit more detail to this in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've taken the liberty to unroll as much as i could to understand what's going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/kritzikratzi/YYwm9/1/

if i understand correctly you expect the following behaviour:

1. fade out
2. do some console.log thing (or process data)
3. fade in

now you can actually try changing the length of the say-hello-loop, for me with `i < 5000` iterations i can see half the animation, with `i < 1` i can see the entire animation and with `i < 10000` the animation vanishes. 
looks like jQuery seems to use the time the last frame was drawn when creating a new animation. javascript is single-threaded, you're completely blocking the browser with your for-loop and then immediately begin the next animation, which messes up all timing -- the animation ends before it even began.

the solution is surprisingly simple: 
DONT call next() immediately, but let jQuery's animate catch up by simply letting the browser repaint quickly and then begin the animation on the next frame. 
long story short:

```
  // instead of this ... 
  next(); 
  // do this...
  window.setTimeout( next, 1 );
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kritzikratzi/YYwm9/2/

well, i hope this is what you were asking for, it's a little unclear what your actual problem is :)

---

to your original question: why does console.log( queue ) not display correctly?

well, if you look at the jQuery source code for queue() you can see the following:

```
queue = jQuery._data( elem, type );
[...]
return queue;
```

so queue might be some odd jQuery object and not directly an array, don't expect it to print correctly. as pointed out in an another answer, using toString() fixes it.

Comment: <3 <3 <3 thank you! That short setTimeout works perfectly! [Here is my working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww8QX/4/) Yeah sorry I didn't know how to ask my question because I didn't know what was wrong haha. Anyways, thanks again!!!

Comment: ah, cool... didn't know that you can do setTimeout( .., 0 ) :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a product of letting the code implicitly convert the array.  If you instead utilize the explicit toString() method on a JavaScript array, I find the output is correct, with no empty array or undefined entries.  In the jsFiddle, change the first of the four console.log lines to:

console.log(elem.queue('jChain').toString());

This explicit conversion of the array to a string seems to get the content back correctly.

Comment: Hmm, yes that fixes my problem specifically when logging it, but my queue still seems to be broken. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure of the underlying cause -- it seems and feels like something is happening concurrently as you say, even though that doesn't really make sense.  But if the toString forces the object to compile, I'd probably try to fudge it by forcing the queue toString(), either redundantly or into a dummy variable, before accessing the queue for use.

Comment: 1.) no. in javascript things don't happen concurently, ever
2.) answer seems accurate, maybe a browser issue (using firebug?). chrome inspector shows the array correctly

Comment: @kritzikratzi - It seems you misunderstood the question. I am using chrome, and although calling toString() on the queue logs it correctly, that doesn't solve the problem where the queue "jumps" through the second animation call. Maybe you have a suggestion on how to fix that?